# Is there a PHP equvalent of Objective-C Categories?

Tags: php, oop, helper, categories

For the short period of time I subjected myself to Objective-C, I swore a lot, but one thing I thought was fabulous was categories.

I could add a method to the NSString object as a category, and it was available on any NSString object in my application.  Something similar is now possible in Delphi and probably many other languages.

Is that possible in PHP?

If so is there a good tutorial, and can I extend the PDO object?

I have searched helpers and categories with little success. I seem to remember reading that it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible in PHP to add functionality to existing native classes.

And yes it is indeed possible to extend PDO.

```
class MyClass extends PDO { /* All your class stuff here */ }
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can extend PDO, but I was hoping I could just add a helper class and just use PDO.  Thanks for the answer.